# an often scroll-shaped bracket used for decoration or for supporting a projecting member, SUCH AS a cornice or shelf

Tags: meaning-in-context

Console can be defined as "[an often scroll-shaped bracket used for decoration or for supporting a projecting member, such as a cornice or shelf](https://www.thefreedictionary.com/console)". Does "cornice or shelf" refer to the projecting member or to the console itself? It should be really easy to understand, but the somehow I got confused. Thank you!

Comment: A console can be decorative or used to support e.g. a cornice or shelf. These are types of projecting members.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a very rare use of the word. You can probably survive without knowing this word!

The definition is formally ambiguous, but "shelves and cornice" are not brackets and nor would they be scroll-shaped. On the other hand, it is quite possible for the thing that supports a shelf to be scroll-shaped.

So you would have to assume that the "cornice or shelf" is the "projecting member", and not the console.

[Britannica offers the following image:](https://www.britannica.com/technology/console-architecture#/media/1/133596/201818)

[image]

Comment: Extreme sense development from latin "con + solari" (compare solace) to "supporter" to THe thing that supports a shelf.  From this it develops to mean other bits of furniture, including the body of a musical organ.  It is generalised to mean the "control panel" of an organ, and then shifted sideways to mean the control keyboard of a computer.  It left definitions as the sense changed, so we can talk about console brackets, console tables, consoles for a radio, the console of a car, consoles on an organ, and talk about commands typed at the console of a computer.

Comment: Thank you also very much for you detailed explanations!